# CKEditor - pass existing image path to file browser

Tags: ckeditor

I am using the latest CKEditor (4.9.2). I have integrated it successfully with a file browser (DevExpress) and everything works fine.

I use an initial upload path, common for both files and images. This directory has a quite large and complex structure (usually up to 6-7 levels). If the user wants to replace an existing image or file the file browser opens and he has to open six or seven folders in order to get to the folder that the new image is stored. Usually, the images the users replace are stored in the same folder with the one they are replacing. In my opinion, that should be the default behavior. If I select to see an existing image’s properties and then I hit the “Browse Server” button, to have the file browser to open in the folder the image resides.

[image: example path]

Is there any way to pass the current image path, in the image url field,  to the file manager? In that case with a little parsing I can set the file browser’s initial path to the same folder the existing image is stored.

Is that possible? I imagine that we must first get the image path from the image URL field and alter the “Browse Server” button’s code to pass it as a url parameter to the file browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit 'hackish', but inside your file manager, you can use this to get the existing value of `URL` field:

```
window.opener.CKEDITOR.document.$.getElementsByClassName('cke_dialog_image_url')[0].querySelector('input').value
```

`cke_dialog_image_url` is the CSS classname of the `table` that has the URL `input` field.